# type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I got this problem when trying to serialize complex JSON that i fetch from the internet using json_serializable and using FutureProvider to connect them together. This is the json file,

```
{
  "data": {
    "quiz": {
      "stats": {
        "played": 6691,
        "totalPlayers": "29553"
      },
      "publishedVersion": "5a13431202b92110003fdb92",
      "_id": "5a133e2302b92110003fd8ef",
      "createdBy": {
        "local": {
          "username": "jshutt"
        },
        "occupation": "teacher_school"
      }, //createdBy
      "info": {
        "name": "Proportional Relationships",
        "image": "https://quizizz.com/media/resource/gs/quizizz-media/quizzes/L2FwcGhvc3RpbmdfcHJvZC9ibG9icy9BRW5CMlVyNUFUSlN0VXhVSzcxY1hHZGN4UmJYVEdiWHRpeXBCcmVvQXhwT0JhckZwdnhBdkw4cHFqYjNVNktJSnlwSEdtUlJubV9Nc2Qxck51Z2Z5ampNSzJWb09Qek1tU0Joc0NaSUZtdGNyYzlQN1ZUQWREQS5EOUxuUGh3MUxaZzk0MUYz",
        "subjects": [
          "Mathematics"
        ],
        "topics": [
          "Pre-algebra"
        ],
        "subtopics": [
          "Proportional relationships",
          "Constant of Proportionality",
          "proportional graphs",
          "proportion equations"
        ],
        "questions": [
          {
            "structure": {
              "kind": "MCQ",
              "query": {
                "media": [
                  {
                    "url": "https://quizizz.com/media/resource/gs/quizizz-media/questions/L2FwcGhvc3RpbmdfcHJvZC9ibG9icy9BRW5CMlVwajVWZnl0S2RBRXpIazROejFaSTl0dkU3Rmt6cjhtcTRvTGVxeFJzeHVLQzlZa3hzYjNZdkpNa3N1TTItaE5UNmVHUUZVdl9ZdTR6YnNaTk5hV0luZWhZQm9sUS5pOTBwLU1YLUtMRXR5YlBZ"
                  }
                ], //media
                "text": "Write an equation for this relationship.",
              }, //query
              "options": [
                {
                  "text": "y=1/5x"
                },
                {
                  "text": "y=1/2x"
                },
                {
                  "text": "y=2x"
                },
                {
                  "text": "y=5x"
                }
              ], //options
              "answer": 3
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

This is the code that contain the class for the serialization,

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';
import 'questions_data/questions_quiz.dart';

part 'questions.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class CoreData {
  QuestionData data;

  CoreData({this.data});

  factory CoreData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$CoreDataFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$CoreDataToJson(this);
}

@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class QuestionData {
  Quiz quiz;

  QuestionData({this.quiz});

  factory QuestionData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$QuestionDataFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$QuestionDataToJson(this);
}
@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class QuestionsList {
  List<Questions> questions;

  QuestionsList({this.questions});

  factory QuestionsList.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$QuestionsListFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$QuestionsListToJson(this);
}

@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class Questions {
  Structure structure;

  Questions({this.structure});

  factory Questions.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$QuestionsFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$QuestionsToJson(this);
}

@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class Structure {
  String kind;
  Query query;
  Options options;
  int answer;

  Structure({this.kind, this.query, this.options, this.answer});

  factory Structure.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$StructureFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$StructureToJson(this);
}
@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class Quiz {
  String publishedVersion;
  @JsonKey(name: '_id')
  String id;
  Stats stats;
  CreatedBy createdBy;
  Info info;

  Quiz({this.publishedVersion, this.id, this.stats, this.createdBy, this.info});

  factory Quiz.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$QuizFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$QuizToJson(this);
}

@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class CreatedBy {
  Local local;
  String occupation;

  CreatedBy({this.local, this.occupation});

  factory CreatedBy.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$CreatedByFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$CreatedByToJson(this);
}

@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class Local {
  String username;

  Local({this.username});

  factory Local.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$LocalFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$LocalToJson(this);
}

@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class Stats {
  int played;
  int totalPlayers;

  Stats({this.played, this.totalPlayers});

  factory Stats.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$StatsFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$StatsToJson(this);
}

@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class Info {
  String name;
  String image;
  List<String> subjects, topics, subtopics;
  Questions questions;

  Info({
      this.name,
      this.image,
      this.subjects,
      this.topics,
      this.subtopics,
      this.questions});

  factory Info.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$InfoFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$InfoToJson(this);
}
@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class Query {
  String text;
  List<Images> media;

  Query({this.text, this.media});

  factory Query.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$QueryFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$QueryToJson(this);
}

@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class Images {
  String url;
  
  Images({this.url});

  factory Images.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$ImagesFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$ImagesToJson(this);
}

@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class Options {
  List<QuestionText> options;

  Options ({this.options});

  factory Options.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$OptionsFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$OptionsToJson(this);
}

@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class QuestionText {
  String text;

  QuestionText({this.text});

  factory QuestionText.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$QuestionTextFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$QuestionTextToJson(this);
}
```

The future provider to fetch the json file and convert it to dart,

```
import 'dart:convert' as convert;
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:quizizz_cheat/models/questions.dart';

    class QuestionsService {
      Future<CoreData> fetchQuestion() async {
        final response = await http.get(url);
        var jsonResponse = convert.jsonDecode(response.body);
        CoreData parsedQuestions = CoreData.fromJson(jsonResponse);
        
        return parsedQuestions;
      }
    }
```

This is the genearted code,

```
part of 'questions.dart';

// **************************************************************************
// JsonSerializableGenerator
// **************************************************************************

CoreData _$CoreDataFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return CoreData(
    data: json['data'] == null
        ? null
        : QuestionData.fromJson(json['data'] as Map<String, dynamic>),
  );
}

Map<String, dynamic> _$CoreDataToJson(CoreData instance) => <String, dynamic>{
      'data': instance.data?.toJson(),
    };

QuestionData _$QuestionDataFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return QuestionData(
    quiz: json['quiz'] == null
        ? null
        : Quiz.fromJson(json['quiz'] as Map<String, dynamic>),
  );
}

Map<String, dynamic> _$QuestionDataToJson(QuestionData instance) =>
    <String, dynamic>{
      'quiz': instance.quiz?.toJson(),
    };
QuestionsList _$QuestionsListFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return QuestionsList(
    questions: (json['questions'] as List)
        ?.map((e) =>
            e == null ? null : Questions.fromJson(e as Map<String, dynamic>))
        ?.toList(),
  );
}

Map<String, dynamic> _$QuestionsListToJson(QuestionsList instance) =>
    <String, dynamic>{
      'questions': instance.questions?.map((e) => e?.toJson())?.toList(),
    };

Questions _$QuestionsFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return Questions(
    structure: json['structure'] == null
        ? null
        : Structure.fromJson(json['structure'] as Map<String, dynamic>),
  );
}

Map<String, dynamic> _$QuestionsToJson(Questions instance) => <String, dynamic>{
      'structure': instance.structure?.toJson(),
    };

Structure _$StructureFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return Structure(
    kind: json['kind'] as String,
    query: json['query'] == null
        ? null
        : Query.fromJson(json['query'] as Map<String, dynamic>),
    options: json['options'] == null
        ? null
        : Options.fromJson(json['options'] as Map<String, dynamic>),
    answer: json['answer'] as int,
  );
}

Map<String, dynamic> _$StructureToJson(Structure instance) => <String, dynamic>{
      'kind': instance.kind,
      'query': instance.query?.toJson(),
      'options': instance.options?.toJson(),
      'answer': instance.answer,
    };
Quiz _$QuizFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return Quiz(
    publishedVersion: json['publishedVersion'] as String,
    id: json['_id'] as String,
    stats: json['stats'] == null
        ? null
        : Stats.fromJson(json['stats'] as Map<String, dynamic>),
    createdBy: json['createdBy'] == null
        ? null
        : CreatedBy.fromJson(json['createdBy'] as Map<String, dynamic>),
    info: json['info'] == null
        ? null
        : Info.fromJson(json['info'] as Map<String, dynamic>),
  );
}

Map<String, dynamic> _$QuizToJson(Quiz instance) => <String, dynamic>{
      'publishedVersion': instance.publishedVersion,
      '_id': instance.id,
      'stats': instance.stats?.toJson(),
      'createdBy': instance.createdBy?.toJson(),
      'info': instance.info?.toJson(),
    };

CreatedBy _$CreatedByFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return CreatedBy(
    local: json['local'] == null
        ? null
        : Local.fromJson(json['local'] as Map<String, dynamic>),
    occupation: json['occupation'] as String,
  );
}

Map<String, dynamic> _$CreatedByToJson(CreatedBy instance) => <String, dynamic>{
      'local': instance.local?.toJson(),
      'occupation': instance.occupation,
    };

Local _$LocalFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return Local(
    username: json['username'] as String,
  );
}

Map<String, dynamic> _$LocalToJson(Local instance) => <String, dynamic>{
      'username': instance.username,
    };

Stats _$StatsFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return Stats(
    played: json['played'] as int,
    totalPlayers: json['totalPlayers'] as int,
  );
}

Map<String, dynamic> _$StatsToJson(Stats instance) => <String, dynamic>{
      'played': instance.played,
      'totalPlayers': instance.totalPlayers,
    };

Info _$InfoFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return Info(
    name: json['name'] as String,
    image: json['image'] as String,
    subjects: (json['subjects'] as List)?.map((e) => e as String)?.toList(),
    topics: (json['topics'] as List)?.map((e) => e as String)?.toList(),
    subtopics: (json['subtopics'] as List)?.map((e) => e as String)?.toList(),
    questions: json['questions'] == null
        ? null
        : Questions.fromJson(json['questions'] as Map<String, dynamic>),
  );
}

Map<String, dynamic> _$InfoToJson(Info instance) => <String, dynamic>{
      'name': instance.name,
      'image': instance.image,
      'subjects': instance.subjects,
      'topics': instance.topics,
      'subtopics': instance.subtopics,
      'questions': instance.questions?.toJson(),
    };
Query _$QueryFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return Query(
    text: json['text'] as String,
    media: (json['media'] as List)
        ?.map((e) =>
            e == null ? null : Images.fromJson(e as Map<String, dynamic>))
        ?.toList(),
  );
}

Map<String, dynamic> _$QueryToJson(Query instance) => <String, dynamic>{
      'text': instance.text,
      'media': instance.media?.map((e) => e?.toJson())?.toList(),
    };

Images _$ImagesFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return Images(
    url: json['url'] as String,
  );
}

Map<String, dynamic> _$ImagesToJson(Images instance) => <String, dynamic>{
      'url': instance.url,
    };

Options _$OptionsFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return Options(
    options: (json['options'] as List)
        ?.map((e) =>
            e == null ? null : QuestionText.fromJson(e as Map<String, dynamic>))
        ?.toList(),
  );
}

Map<String, dynamic> _$OptionsToJson(Options instance) => <String, dynamic>{
      'options': instance.options?.map((e) => e?.toJson())?.toList(),
    };

QuestionText _$QuestionTextFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return QuestionText(
    text: json['text'] as String,
  );
}

Map<String, dynamic> _$QuestionTextToJson(QuestionText instance) =>
    <String, dynamic>{
      'text': instance.text,
    };
```

and this is the code where the converted json file shows up

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:quiz/screens/home.dart';
import 'package:quiz/services/questions_service.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final QuestionsService questionsService = QuestionsService();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureProvider(
      create: (context) async => questionsService.fetchQuestion(),
      catchError: (context, error) {
        print(error.toString());
      },
          child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Quizizz cheat',
        home: HomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var question = Provider.of<CoreData>(context);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Quizizz Cheat'),
      ),
      body: question == null
          ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
          : Center(
              child: Text(question.data.quiz.info.questions.structure.kind),
          ),
    );
  }
}
```

When i try to run the project i got this error

> I/flutter (23347): type 'List' is not a subtype of type
> 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast

I believe the problem comes from this code that trying to convert a json containing list of maps and the code that contain the json serialization method

```
@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
    class QuestionsList {
      List<Questions> questions;
    
      QuestionsList({this.questions});
    
      factory QuestionsList.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$QuestionsListFromJson(json);
      Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$QuestionsListToJson(this);
    }
```

Comment: um, its hard to know where the problem, since you didn't  include the generated parts. if you are using android studio, there are more easy way to do it, install json to dart plugins, and use it. just paste your json on it, and it will generate the classes that needed in order to convert it into objects.

Comment: I'm sorry for the lack of information. But i already tried using the json to dart converted websites but it's not generating the result. So i use json_serializble to serialize the json file to dart. I added the generated code in the body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already fixed the problem, it seems that i need to be more careful at writing my code. The answer was simple, i need to change the type from this...

```
@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class Info {
  String name;
  String image;
  List<String> subjects, topics, subtopics;
  Questions questions;

  Info({
      this.name,
      this.image,
      this.subjects,
      this.topics,
      this.subtopics,
      this.questions});

  factory Info.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$InfoFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$InfoToJson(this);
}
```

to this...

```
@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class Info {
  String name;
  String image;
  List<String> subjects, topics, subtopics;
  List<Questions> questions;

  Info({
      this.name,
      this.image,
      this.subjects,
      this.topics,
      this.subtopics,
      this.questions});

  factory Info.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$InfoFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$InfoToJson(this);
}
```

and from this...

```
@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class Structure {
  String kind;
  Query query;
  Options options;
  int answer;

  Structure({this.kind, this.query, this.options, this.answer});

  factory Structure.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$StructureFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$StructureToJson(this);
}
```

to this...

```
@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class Structure {
  String kind;
  Query query;
  List<QuestionText> options;
  int answer;

  Structure({this.kind, this.query, this.options, this.answer});

  factory Structure.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$StructureFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$StructureToJson(this);
}
```